# Find maximum of x given a bunch of constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

Trying to find maximum of x given that '''0<=x<=3''' and some other stuff. This works fine:

```
Clear[x, y]
FindMaximum[{x, 0<=x<=3}, x]
```

But this does not:

```
Clear[x, y]
FindMaximum[{x, 0<=x<=3 && y==1}, x]
```

How can I get the maximum x from the second list of constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FindArgMax[{x, 0 <= x <= 3 && y == 1}, {x, y}][[1]]
```

> 3.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but finds a local maximum. For example, if the constraints are `0<=x<=1 && x==2,y==1` it finds 1, not 2. I have been using `rule = NMaximize[{x,0<=x<=1 && x==2,y==1},{x,y}]` and `x/.rule` to good effect so far.